Memory limit exceeded in leetcode problem number 802 Find Eventual safe states
I tried to solve the question using  topological sort using BFS .
Here's the code
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> eventualSafeNodes(int[][] graph) {
        int n = graph.length;
        int m = graph[0].length;
        int V [][]= new int[n][m];

        List<List<Integer>> adj=new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> adjRev = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m;i++){
                adjRev.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }       
        }

        int indeg[] = new int[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m;i++){
                for(int it : adj.get(i)){
                adjRev.get(it).add(i);
                indeg[i]++;
            }
            }
        }

        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> safeNodes = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<n ;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m;i++){
                if(indeg[i]==0){
                q.add(i);
                }
            }
           
        }

        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            int node = q.peek();
            q.remove();
            safeNodes.add(node);
            for(int it : adjRev.get(node)){
                indeg[it]-- ;
                if(indeg[it] == 0) q.add(it);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(safeNodes);
        return safeNodes;
    }
}

Earlier the code was facing index out of bound error .So I tried to fox it by taking a two dimensional Array named 'V' with 'n' number of rows and 'm' number of columns which had the count of adjacency matrix of the given graph.

Look at this line: for(int j=0;j<m;i++)

There is no reason to use a LinkedList EVER. Use an ArrayList or a ArrayDeque instead.

Are you referring to this Leetcode problem? And are you saying that Leetcode reports Memory limit exceeded when you run your solution?

@ValerijDobler if There is no reason to use a LinkedList EVER then I'm wondering why it is in the JDK in the first place. I assume that the authors of the JDK classes did believe that there are reasons. Can you explain why there are not?

@Abra it's quite obvious that memory limit would be exceeded due to the memory allocation inside an infinite loop in this code.

@Abra from the author of Java's LinkedList himself: https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248

@k314159 I just wanted to clarify any ambiguities.

@Abra take a look at the implementation. Its memory overhead is garbage. If you need a (double-ended) queue, use an ArrayDeque otherwise an ArrayList usually does the job.

Regarding LinkedList Based on what I've read and tested, I'm surprised it isn't deprecated.
